# Anonymous block in taking time to delete duplicate data || Checks for duplicates and then delete. But the loop keeps running and doesnt stop

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sequence

Delete should happen based on the minimum sequence id(column -contract_amendment_curr_id)  which is unique and duplicate field is cont_amd_id. So the old seq id to be deleted (taking the min) for the cont_amd_id

Query has 398 duplicates and table has 900k records

But the loop keeps running. In oracle we can use collection for deleting all the records. How to achieve it here?

```
DECLARE
CURSOR main_cur IS
SELECT min(contract_amendment_curr_id) rd,cont_amd_id
FROM external.eai_contract_amendment_currency_bkp1
GROUP BY cont_amd_id;
BEGIN
FOR i IN main_cur
LOOP
DELETE FROM external.eai_contract_amendment_currency_bkp1 
WHERE contract_amendment_curr_id=i.rd and cont_amd_id=i.cont_amd_id ;
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason for a loop here.

Instead:

```
DELETE FROM external.eai_contract_amendment_currency_bkp1 a 
USING (
    SELECT min(contract_amendment_curr_id) rd ,cont_amd_id
    FROM external.eai_contract_amendment_currency_bkp1
    GROUP BY cont_amd_id
 ) b 
 WHERE a.contract_amendment_curr_id=b.rd and a.cont_amd_id=b.cont_amd_id ;
```

Comment: And if required to be done in a loop then? I have been told to use a for loop and do it.. Also the no of records in a table is 9lakh and duplicates are 398.

Comment: Whoever is requiring you to do this in a loop is a ding dong. Your proc is doing the same thing that this statement is doing, however it's doing it the slowest way possible, inside a loop. 9lakh is small data, but even if it were 9000lakh you would still want to use a set-based approach over a loop. In fact, the larger the data set, the more important a set based approach would be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input @JNevill. It would be great to provide me the code which deletes row by row and not at once. The code I wrote is slow don't know why. If you could share input on how to achieve it.. Thanks !!

Comment: The code you wrote is slow BECAUSE it's row-by-row. As indicated by @JNevill that is the slowest possible way. But it does what you want.

Comment: It's like asking how you can push your car faster. I'm telling you how to fix the engine issue so your car will run, but you really just want to push it... just faster. You'll just never be able to push it as fast as you want. I'm not sure there is anything you can do to your proc code to make it faster. The method you've chosen to delete is inherently slow.